# React: how to add class to elements that contain innerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to check if a table cell has innerHTML attached to it and add a class if it does?

I have a table with hundreds of cells and have to do it dynamically. The content of the cell is being set using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, as follows:

```
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.myFunc('foo')}></td>
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
 <td className={document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML.length === 0 ? '' : 'myClass'} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.myFunc('foo')}></td>
```

Any ideas on how to do it in React?

Comment: How are you rendering the cells? Meaning, are you .map'ing over data that renders the row and td cells? If so, the cell should know if it has data or not when it's rendering, you shouldn't have to call document.getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

[I love the classnames module for adding classnames based on states](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

I would probably do something like this (note that i haven't tested the code, so there might be syntax errors):

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

renderCell(cell, key) {
    if (cell.dangerousHTML) {
        return (
            <td key={i} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={classNames({myClass: cell.dangerousHTML ? true : false})}>
                // I strongly suggest you look into rendering your elements here rather than using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML"
            </td>
        )
    }

    return false
}

render() {
    return (
        <table>
            {this.props.cells.map((cell, i) => {
                return this.renderCell(cell, i)
            })}
        </table>
    )
}
```